# How do I post to Rails using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable through jQuery using the POST method, storing it to a controller, then using that same variable in the Rails HTML to query a table.

It does not seem like it is passing the variable to the controller.

jQuery:

```
var id = 1;

$.post("http://localhost:3000/teamplayers", {'ids': ids});
```

Teamplayers controller:

```
def index
   @teamplayers = Teamplayer.all
   @ids = params[:id]
end
```

Rails HTML:

```
<select id = "test3" style= float:right size= 10>
<% Teamplayer.find_each(:conditions => "teamid = @ids") do |tp| %>
    <option> <%#=@teamplayer.teamid %></option>
    <option>Players on team 1</option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

Also, I tried to use the following Ajax method but it posted my page back into the tag I assigned it to.

Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:3000/teamplayers",success:function(result){
        $('#div1').text(result);
   }});
 });
});
```

What is wrong with the way I am using POST or the Ajax?

Comment: That's not a POST it's a GET. But you might only need just a `$('#div1').load(blah blah blah)`, to hit a server and load the result into a div...

Comment: that loaded the html of my page, i want to load a list of people from my database through my Teamplayer model, how can i do that

Comment: I want to load it to the same page in to a select_tag

Answer (score 2):

One of your first problems is in the controller: you are incorrectly asking for `params[:id]` when you should be asking for `params[:ids]` since you pass it in from jQuery land via `{'ids': ids}`. You also need to pass in a success handler function to the `$.post` function so that you can handle the response and make something ajaxy happen.

Once you've instantiated `@ids` properly you can pass it directly to the model's find method:

```
<% Teamplayer.find(@ids) do |tp| %>
```

And that will find all the Teamplayers with those ids. Here you could be taking advantage of [Rail's form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) to generate that HTML select list. Instead of this:

```
<select id = "test3" style= float:right size= 10>
<% Teamplayer.find_each(:conditions => "teamid = @ids") do |tp| %>
    <option> <%#=@teamplayer.teamid %></option>
    <option>Players on team 1</option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

Do this:

```
<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.find(@ids), "id", "name") %>
```

Note that the last argument to `options_from_collection_for_select` is "name" as an example only. You should change that to the name of the field in your Teamplayer table that you want to use as text in the option tag, I'm guessing it would be `teamid`.

Lastly, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that last ajax call. Hopefully the aforementioned will fix your original problem.

Comment: when i used: `<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.find(@ids), "id", "name") %>` The error page says: Couldn't find Teamplayer without an ID, is it not being passed correctly?

Comment: Did you fix your controller and assigned params[:ids] to @ids? Make sure @ids is set and has an array of integers.

Comment: @ids = params[:ids] just like this

Comment: from the jquery i am only passing the number 1, since i set var ids = 1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have a variable naming problem - rename 'id' to 'ids' where needed:

**jQuery:**

```
var ids = 1;
$.post("http://localhost:3000/teamplayers", {'ids': ids});
```

**Teamplayers Controller:**

```
@ids = params[:ids]
```

Comment: so like this: `var ids = 1; $.post("localhost:3000/teamplayers", {'ids': ids});`

Comment: ok i did that and tried to use that variable in this statement: `<%= select_tag "test3", options_from_collection_for_select(Teamplayer.find(@ids), "id", "playerid") %>` This gave an error: Couldn't find Teamplayer without an ID

Comment: Try removing the quotes around 'ids' in the jQuery:  `$.post("http://localhost:3000/teamplayers", {ids: ids});`

Comment: i tired to declare @ids = [1, 2] in my controller but that did not work